# Custom UI slider , Thumb image size issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, uislider

As I'm making a custom slider , Every thing is working fine . As I have an thumb image having width and height of 30x70. But when i implement the image it change its orientation by itself and displaying in 70x30 .

I tried changing the image also but the Thumb slider comes in 70x30. I want to show image in vertical but it displays in horizontal in `UISlider` .

Can any one help?

```
 [self setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: you want slider in vertical position..??

Answer (score 9):

If you want change UISlider appearance then use below method

     `[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider.png"] 
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Ideal size for thumb image is 25 x 25 pixels check Apple's HIG documentation

Comment: No UIslider is fine , I set it to vertical position using the code

Comment: I think thats what i was looking for .. can you please send me the URL for refrence

Comment: Just provide a different size of sliderThumb@2x.png, @3x and all we work itself out.